# What is the correct way to uninsrtall a app installed using npx?

Tags: node.js, npm, npx

I want to remove a package reinstalled with npx.

I tried removing the package from where it's installed (`C:\Users\vince\AppData\Roaming\npm`) by deleting manually the ps1, bat and the package folder and it still didn't worked.

I tried to remove it using `npx react-devtools --remove` and it still didn't got removed(NPX Didn't showed any output indicating that it sucessfully removed react-devtools). Here is how the command look:

```
PS C:\Users\vince\project\js\tinder-cli> npx react-devtools --remove
```

I expect npx to remove react-devtools with a sucess message or something like a sucess message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uninstall the package by deleting all the content of the directory: `C:\Users\vince\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx`