# How do I uninstall depcheck/npx?

Tags: laravel, windows, npm, package-managers, npx

I made the mistake of running `npx depcheck` and pressing Y when it prompted me to install it. Now whenever I run `npm run dev` I see warnings of future deprecations, mostly in upstream codebases I'm not even responsible for, and I'm unable to uninstall `depcheck` because it isn't listed in my `package.lock`, searching for it in my project with VS Code doesn't do anything, and searching for it on my *entire system* with Everything doesn't show anything. Somehow, `depcheck` doesn't exist and yet still pops up to warn me about deprecation errors everytime I try to build my project.

This seems more like a problem with `npx` than `depcheck` because I've run `npm install depcheck` before without issue. Something about `npx` seems to create invisible packages that can't be removed and that attach themselves to scripts like `npm run dev` without permission, which seems pretty close to the definition of malware to me.

Here's the current output of my `npm run dev`:

```
$ npm run dev

> dev
> npm run development


> development
> mix


* Mix █████████████████████████ building (37%) 4/8 entries 339/339 dependencies 113/120 modules 5 activ
e
css-loader » postcss-loader » resources\css\payments.css|0

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet


* Mix █████████████████████████ building (58%) 7/8 entries 340/340 dependencies 119/121 modules 2 activ
e
css-loader » postcss-loader » sass-loader » resources\sass\app.scss|0

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet


* Mix █████████████████████████ sealing (75%) chunk optimization
RemoveEmptyChunksPlugin

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet


* Mix █████████████████████████ sealing (88%)
runtime requirements

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet


* Mix █████████████████████████ sealing (92%)
asset processing

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet


* Mix █████████████████████████ emitting (95%)
emit

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet


* Mix █████████████████████████ emitting (98%)
after emit

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(40%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{40%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
65 │     $alert-color: mix($value, color-contrast($alert-background), abs($alert-color-scale));
│                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_alert.scss 65:66  @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 34:9                   root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(40%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{40%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

    ╷
187 │     $list-group-variant-color: mix($value, color-contrast($list-group-variant-bg), abs($list-group-
item-color-scale));
    │                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_list-group.scss 187:84  @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 36:9                         root stylesheet




* Mix █████████████████████████ done (99%) plugins
WebpackBar:done

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(40%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{40%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
65 │     $alert-color: mix($value, color-contrast($alert-background), abs($alert-color-scale));
│                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_alert.scss 65:66  @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 34:9                   root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(40%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{40%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

    ╷
187 │     $list-group-variant-color: mix($value, color-contrast($list-group-variant-bg), abs($list-group-
item-color-scale));
    │                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_list-group.scss 187:84  @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 36:9                         root stylesheet

√ Mix
Compiled successfully in 18.97s

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(100%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{100%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
57 │   $dividend: abs($dividend);
│              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\vendor\_rfs.scss 57:14         divide()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 59:12        row-cols()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 85:13        @content
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_breakpoints.scss 68:5  media-breakpoint-up()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_grid.scss 72:5         make-grid-columns()
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_grid.scss 32:3                @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 20:9                               root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(40%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{40%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

╷
65 │     $alert-color: mix($value, color-contrast($alert-background), abs($alert-color-scale));
│                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_alert.scss 65:66  @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 34:9                   root stylesheet

Deprecation Warning: Passing percentage units to the global abs() function is deprecated.
In the future, this will emit a CSS abs() function to be resolved by the browser.
To preserve current behavior: math.abs(40%)
To emit a CSS abs() now: abs(#{40%})
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/abs-percent

    ╷
187 │     $list-group-variant-color: mix($value, color-contrast($list-group-variant-bg), abs($list-group-
item-color-scale));
    │                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_list-group.scss 187:84  @import
    resources\sass\app.scss 36:9                         root stylesheet


Laravel Mix v6.0.49


✔ Compiled Successfully in 18693ms
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│                                                                                       File │ Size     │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│                                                                                 /js/app.js │ 14.2 KiB │
│                                                                                /js/main.js │ 30.7 KiB │
│                                                                            /js/manifest.js │ 7.66 KiB │
│                                                                             /js/success.js │ 3.53 KiB │
│                                                                              /js/vendor.js │ 2.33 MiB │
│                                                                                css/app.css │ 542 KiB  │
│                                                                               css/main.css │ 28 KiB   │
│                                                                           css/payments.css │ 4.53 KiB │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┘
webpack compiled successfully
```

`which depcheck` returns nothing but `which npx` tells me that `npx` is installed globally to Windows rather than my current project. Packages for it are [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67061772/what-is-the-correct-way-to-uninsrtall-a-app-installed-using-npx) installed to `D:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache`, but there's no entry for npx there or in `LocalLow`. I did find and remove `D:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx`, but this hasn't changed anything even after a reboot.

How do I nuke this thing already?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to think that `depcheck` or `npx` are somehow responsible for the deprecation warnings, but I'm not sure why you think that, nowhere in your log output is any of them even mentioned. Also, `depcheck` probably doesn't even exist on your machine anymore because when you use `npx`, it will temporarily download and install the package, run it, and then delete it again. (It might exist in the npm cache but that doesn't do anything, it's just a cache.)

It's simply the case that Sass deprecated the option to pass `%` to the global CSS function `abs` but Bootstrap still uses it, causing this warning [emitted by `dart-sass`](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/af0118ad6409bbe54bc5d0f8347458ea68703946/lib/src/functions/math.dart#L22) since version 1.65.0 (August 17th, 2023). Probably you recently updated your dependencies or at least `dart-sass` to a newer version which started deprecating this feature.

[There is an open GitHub issue about this in the Bootstrap repository.](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/39028) You have to wait for them to fix it and update Bootstrap then. Until then, ignore it, you can't do anything about it anyway (other than perhaps pinning `dart-sass` to an older version (1.64.1) that doesn't yet have the feature deprecated, but that's usually not the right solution). It also doesn't cause any harm.

Comment: I'm aware it's a Bootstrap deprecation but I've run `npm run dev`/Laravel Mix hundreds of times and never had a deprecation warning appear until the first build after I ran `npx depcheck`, so it seems highly unlikely that neither `depcheck` or `npx` are responsible. The only other changes during that period are the removal of jQuery 3.6.0 and `postcss-purgecss`, neither of which seem likely to have anything to do with this.

Comment: Perhaps `postcss-purgecss` previously removed that unused CSS that contains the usage of the deprecated function so no warning was displayed before?

Comment: No, I removed it because it had been disabled for a while, due to it removing the application's dynamic but definitely used CSS.

Comment: Then I can only assume at some point you ran `npm update` or otherwise caused Sass to be updated and previously had a version without this deprecation. But `depcheck` and `npx` most definitely can't cause this. I get the same warning when running a build in a CI pipeline inside a docker container that is spun up for that build task only and never saw `depcheck` in its (short) life... It's pretty normal to get this warning.

Comment: I'm sure it's normal to get these warnings in your environment, but as I said, on mine running Laravel Mix, I'd never seen them before running `npx depcheck`, and version control doesn't show any other package changes than the ones I mentioned above. Add to all that the fact that the output comes directly from `depcheck` - you can install `depcheck` and run it in a repo to confirm - and it's pretty clearly a `depcheck` and/or `npx` issue. *Something* is suddenly causing `depcheck` to run everytime I run `npm run dev`.

Comment: The output doesn't come from `depcheck`. I still don't know why you think so. It comes from `dart-sass` as you can see [here in its source code](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/blob/af0118ad6409bbe54bc5d0f8347458ea68703946/lib/src/functions/math.dart#L22), the exact message you see is emitted there. You can also check the opposite, download [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and run it with a filter set to `Path` `includes` `depcheck` while you run `npm run dev` and you'll get zero hits (= no access to anything with `depcheck` in the filename)

Comment: "version control doesn't show any other package changes than the ones I mentioned above" - do you have `package-lock.json` commited to your repository or is it ignored? I would expect a change there in regards to the installed version of `dart-sass`.

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isTw9.png) is how `depcheck` output normally looks... very different from yours. Also note that `dep` stands for "dependency", not "deprecation".

Comment: ...OK I see now why you think `depcheck` has a similar output, but that's just because `depcheck` will use part of your Webpack setup to analyze your project, so in the process the same warning appears which you see when you build normally. But the causality is not the way you think - you saw this output when you ran `depcheck` because `dart-sass` produced it in your project while `depcheck` was analyzing it, not the other way round. You can confirm that with my link above which shows you exactly where that warning originates.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what exactly is suddenly causing `depcheck` to run everytime I run `npm run dev`- and therefore, have no idea how to properly fix it - but I did find a workaround that'll stop me from going crazy: adding a third argument to my Sass build step in `webpack.mix.js` to pass in the `quietDeps: true` Sass option:

```
  .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css", {
    sassOptions: {
      quietDeps: true,
    },
  })
```

It's annoying that I'm suddenly having to use it where I never needed to before, but I'd rather this than suffer any more deprecation warnings.